# GDAL: use virtual file system (VSI) as datasource in virtual format (VRT files)

Tags: gdal, vrt

I cant' make something like that work:

```xml
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="adresses-33">
        <SrcDataSource>/vsigzip//vsicurl/https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/data/ban/adresses/latest/csv/adresses-33.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>EPSG:4326</LayerSRS>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Am I missing something or it's simply not possible to use VSI syntax as datasource in *.vrt files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it to the following

```xml
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="adresses-33">
        <SrcDataSource>/vsigzip//vsicurl/https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/data/ban/adresses/latest/csv/adresses-33.csv.gz</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>EPSG:4326</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="lon" y="lat"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Considering a file `debug.vrt` with the above content, it's working  using below command

```
ogrinfo -so -al debug.vrt
```

The changes made are

- `adresses-33.csv` has to be `adresses-33.csv.gz` because url https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/data/ban/adresses/latest/csv/adresses-33.csv returns a 404 whereas https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/data/ban/adresses/latest/csv/adresses-33.csv.gz exists
- add `<GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="lon" y="lat"/>` to make GDAL understand how to interpret columns as geometry

Comment: Oh thanks Thomas, that was just a typo with the gz extension -_-.

For the GeometryField, don't worry, I just partially copied my file here.